# Firebase querying by date range always returns empty array

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my database I have all the documents saved on the day 23 of this month as the image below shows

[image]

Even if i pass the start date in day 20 it will return empty value.

Here is my query snippet:

```
const documents = await admin.firestore()
    .collection('orders')
    .orderBy('payment_type')
    .startAt('2020-06-22')
    .endAt('2020-06-23')
    .get()
```

I'm new to firebase, so I don't know where i'm missing and the docs were not much of help.
Also, i'm using cloud functions if the information helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're ordering by `payment_type`, which isn't a date value. Suggest you update that to `date` instead so that the respective `startAt` and `endAt` functions will target the correct field. [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

```
const documents = await admin.firestore()
    .collection('orders')
    .orderBy('date')
    .startAt('2020-06-22')
    .endAt('2020-06-25')
    .get()
```

Also, extend the value of your `endAt` to encompass June 24th.

Comment: Hi, Sunny! Thank you for your answer. I did as you sugested and unfortunately it didnt work. :/

Answer (score 1):

The value you pass to `startAt` and `endAt` has to correspond to the fields you're using for ordering.  Since you're ordering on payment_type, the start and end values don't make sense - they are looking for ranges of values that don't match at all payment_type values at all.  Also, it doesn't make sense to use `startAt` and `endAt` unless you are trying to do [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors), which it doesn't look like you are here.

If you're trying to do a range query between two dates, then order the results by payment_type, that's actually not possible with Firestore using the data you have now.  You can't have a range query on a field that's different than the fields you're using to order.  Note the [limitation in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations):

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your
> first ordering must be on the same field:
>
> ```
> citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("population")
> ```

So, you can try a range query by date:

```
const documents = await admin.firestore()
    .collection('orders')
    .where('date', '>', '2020-06-22')
    .where('date', '<', '2020-06-23')
    .get()
```

The order the results on the client by payment_type if you want.

Comment: Hi, Doug! Thanks for helping. I did as you suggested using where('date', '>', '2020-06-22') and where('date', '<', '2020-06-23') and still I get no data. Do you have an example online where I can replicate this type of query? If you need more information let me know

Comment: This is a standard range query, as described in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries

Comment: I will also point out that if your date field is not actually a string as you show it in the JSON, then you won't be able to query it like this with formatted strings.  If it's actually a timestamp, then you will need  to provide Date or Timestamp objects in the query.

Comment: hm you are right i'm not saving as string but as timestamp and transform it before send to client with toDate() function. How do I query a timestamp in my firestore?

Comment: As I said, you need to provide a Date or Timestamp object to the query instead of a string.

Comment: Hi, Doug! Following your instuctions I managed to make it work! by passing .where('date', '>', new Date('Jun 23 2020')) and .where('date', '<', new Date('Jun 24 2020')) I was able to fetch all my data from day 23. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, i'm experiencing some odd problems if I test the query on my localhost it works fine but on deploy it doesn't. For example, if I want to fetch data from day 23, I have to pass Date('Jun 24 2020') and Date('Jun 25 2020'). I don't understand why

Comment: That sounds like a completely new problem.  You should post that as a new question, and be sure to sure exactly what isn't working the way you expect.  We will need to see specific examples and data.

Comment: [I just did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605406/firebase-querying-by-date-not-working-after-deploy), hope it can help