# Firebase querying by date not working after deploy

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on a REST API with firebase and I'm querying some data by date. It works fine on the localhost but after deploy, it does not! I'm also using momentjs to help to deal with dates.

The date field of my document is a timestamp.

Here is how I'm doing my query:

```
const documents = await admin.firestore()
  .collection('orders')
  .where('date', '>', moment('2020-06-23'))
  .where('date', '<', moment('2020-06-24'))
  .get()
```

I have also done the same thing with Date() instead of momentjs

```
const documents = await admin.firestore()
  .collection('orders')
  .where('date', '>', new Date('Jun 23 2020'))
  .where('date', '<', new Date('Jun 24 2020'))
  .get()
```

Both of them works fine on localhost but after deploy the only way to fetch data from day 23 is passing day 24 and 25 on the query like below:

```
const documents = await admin.firestore()
  .collection('orders')
  .where('date', '>', moment('2020-06-24'))
  .where('date', '<', moment('2020-06-25'))
  .get()
```

Part of the data saved on my database:

[image]

[image]

I just want to fetch data by a specific date, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "It works fine on localhost", do you mean that the queries work when run against the local Firestore emulator?

Comment: As I mentioned in your other question, you will need to show the source data that you're querying.  Without knowing what you expect to be returned from actual data, we can't see if your query is actually doing the right thing.  Please edit the question to include enough information that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.  That could involve screenshots of data that do and do not get matched by your query.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, if I run firebase deploy and try It the results will be different

Comment: @DougStevenson I have update and added some images, hope it can helps

Comment: The values of the `date` fields in the first screenshot are strings. What is this a screenshot of?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It is a screenshot of the response of the data that I want to fetch by date. The date fields are showing as strings because i'm using toDate() function before send to my client.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Based on that I'd say this is most likely an issue with timezones, since your local machine likely runs in a different timezone than Cloud Firestore (the URC-3 in your second screenshpt). Consider setting a timezone when you construct the data, so that the underlying value matches what is stored in the database.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you point some reference of how I could set the timezone?

Comment: @UrielCarneiro did you figure this out?

Comment: @S.Ramjit I did not, sorry. Do you? If so, I would like to learn.

Comment: @UrielCarneiro I think I did but I didn't use moment :/ check out my question and answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480197/cloud-functions-not-offsetting-date-for-firestore-query/65503002#65503002

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Date object in JavaScript without specifying a specific moment in time, it uses midnight of the provided date using the timezone of the machine running the code.  Your computer's sense of midnight is going to be different than other computers in other timezones.

In order to do this query in a way that's predictable, you will have to come up with a specific moment in time, regardless of timezone, and use that in your queries.

Bear in mind that the timestamps you see in the Firebase console are formatted to use the local computer's sense of timezone.  A timestamp in Firestore doesn't actually have any timezone - they are all measured in UTC.