# Cloud functions not offsetting date for firestore query

Tags: javascript, date, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a cron job that runs @12PM everyday. It's supposed to grab all the documents in a collection that were added between 6AM and 12PM on that day. I'm using a field called `dateOrderAdded` to run the query on. This field is in the timezone GMT -4 so when I'm running the query I have to cater for that.

```
"use strict";
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendTwelvePmOrderSummary = functions.pubsub.schedule("0 12 * * *")
.timeZone("America/Caracas")
.onRun(async context => {
    //Get current date
    const today = new Date();

    //Set time to 6AM
    const todaySixAm = new Date(today.setHours(6,0,0,0));   

    //Set time to 12PM
    const todayTwelvePm = new Date(today.setHours(12,0,0,0)); 

    console.log(todaySixAm.valueOf());  //browser - 1609149600000 | cloud fn - 1609135200000
    console.log(todayTwelvePm.valueOf()); // browser - 1609171200000 | cloud fn - 1609156800000
    //Get all orders in-between today at 6AM and today at 12PM
    const orderCol = await admin.firestore().collection('orders').where('dateOrderAdded','>=',todaySixAm).where('dateOrderAdded','<=',todayTwelvePm).get();
   
    const orderDocs = orderCol.docs.map(doc=>doc.data())
    if(orderCol.size === 0 ){       
        //No orders placed - TODO: Send no orders placed email
        console.log('No orders placed');
    }else{
        //orders! - TODO: Send order placement summary
        console.log('Orders placed');
    } 
    return null;
}
```

The browser seems to set the hours to 6 and 12 appropriately but on the cloud function it remains at 2 and 8.

Since dates are UTC in cloud functions the hours 2 and 8 make sense but I explicitly set the hours to 6 and 12 and I'm not sure why I'm not seeing the change being set.

Comment: When using *setHours*, you're setting the local hours. To be consistent with Cloud, it seems you need to se the UTC hours using *setUTCHours*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the suggestion from @RobG in the comments I got it to work with setUTC hours.

```
"use strict";
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");


exports.sendTwelvePmOrderSummary = functions.pubsub
.schedule("0 12 * * *")
.timeZone("America/Caracas")
.onRun(async context => {

    //Timezone of stored data is GMT -4 
    //For query to be run correctly use UTC hours
    //6AM = 6+ 4 = 10 UTC hours

    const todaySixAm = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(10,0,0,0));  

    //Set time to 11:59:59:999AM - 12 + 4 = 16
    //Set it to just before 12PM so results from other CRONs won't be duplicated
    const todayTwelvePm = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(15, 59, 59,999));  


    //Get all orders in-between today at 6AM and today at 12PM
    const orderCol = await admin.firestore().collection('orders').where('dateOrderAdded','>=',todaySixAm).where('dateOrderAdded','<=',todayTwelvePm).get();

    const orderDocs = orderCol.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    if (orderCol.size === 0)
        return { message: "No orders placed - TWELVE PM Summary" };
  
    console.log('Orders placed!');
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the `Date` of the Cloud Functions, I recommend you to create the unix timestamp by your own.

The next lines will help to generate the appropiate time, according to a UTC-4 timezone:

*Edit: For Nodejs 10 runtime the format varies so I had to adjust the date in order to avoid generating an incorrect date, if the format varies on the runtime of your choose, just adjust the date to be valid*

```
var date = new Date( ).toLocaleString("es-VE", { "timeZone": "America/Caracas" }).split(", ")[0].split("/");
let today = date[2] + "-" +  date[0] + "-" + date[1];

let todaySixAm = new Date(`${today}T06:00:00.000-04:00`);
let todayTwelvePm = new Date(`${today}T12:00:00.000-04:00`);

console.log("Today 6:00 am GMT-4 " + todaySixAm.valueOf()); //1609322400000
console.log("Today 12:00 pm GMT-4:" + todayTwelvePm.valueOf()); //1609344000000
```

This way you don't have to rely on the local time of the server hosting your code.